# Reverse the order with the maximum value of each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to ponder some table values ​​by reversing the order of the cells in python

**Source Table:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXcUq.png

I need to reverse the order with the maximum value of each row:

**line a:**

```
    5 turns 1
    4 turns 2
    3 stays 3 *(for being the intermediary value)*
    2 turns 4
    1 turns 5
```

**Result:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPED3.png

Is there any function that I can do this?

**Dataframe:**
`list_df = {'Order#1' : [5,8,np.nan], 'Order#2' : [4,6,1],  'Order#3' : [2,2,3], 'Order#4' : [1,1,2], 'Order#5' : [3,7,np.nan], 'Order#6' : [np.nan, 5, np.nan], 'Order#7' : [np.nan, 4, np.nan], 'Order#8' : [np.nan, 3, np.nan]}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data=list_df)`

Comment: please provide your DataFrame as DataFrame constructor, also do you always have consecutive values (e.g., 1,2,3,4)?

Comment: I'm providing the dataframe, sorry about that and yes they are always consecutive

Comment: I don't see your edit with the DataFrame constructor

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to use "Dataframe constructor" so I post the code to make the dataframe in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have consecutive values, you can subtract from the max and add the min per row:

```
out = df.rsub(df.max(1), axis=0).add(df.min(1), axis=0)
```

output:

```
   Order#1  Order#2  Order#3  Order#4  Order#5  Order#6  Order#7  Order#8
0      1.0      2.0      4.0      5.0      3.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
1      1.0      3.0      7.0      8.0      2.0      4.0      5.0      6.0
2      NaN      3.0      1.0      2.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```